# How to make background image using Tailwind CSS with some customization

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui

Can someone tell me the correct way to make a background image with Tailwind CSS? I want to create a circle as a background for texture. I was successful, but as you can see in the image the background has a border [image: Ouput]

I'm not really sure if my way is correct, please tell me.
Thank you.

**HTML**

```
<div class="overlay__about">
    <section style="backdrop-filter: blur(80px);" class="container-2xl bg-slate-900 bg-opacity-90 bg-clip-padding mx-auto" id="home__about">
        <div class="flex lg:items-center md:items-start flex-wrap xl:w-9/12 mx-auto py-44">
            <div class="md:w-6/12 w-full mb-10 md:mb-0 mx-7 sm:mx-7 md:mx-0 lg:mx-0 xl:mx-0">
                <img src="img/how-we-works.svg" class="w-full" />
            </div>
            <div class="md:w-6/12 w-full mx-7 sm:mx-7 md:mx-0 lg:mx-0 xl:mx-0">
                <h2 class="text-sm md:text-sm lg:text-lg xl:text-lg text-text-primary font-medium font-sans leading-relaxed">HOW WE WORKS</h2>
                <h1 class="text-2xl md:text-4xl lg:text-4xl xl:text-4xl text-white font-medium font-sans leading-relaxed mb-5 mt-3">Everything is well planned, well designed and developed wholeheartedly</h1>
                <p class="text-white text-opacity-60 text-lg leading-relaxed">Careful planning makes us confident, developed with best practices so that the project can be maintained. We always test projects before they are shipped.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>

<div class="overlay__team">
    <section style="backdrop-filter: blur(80px);" class="container-2xl bg-slate-900 bg-opacity-90 bg-clip-padding mx-auto" id="home__team">
        <div class="flex lg:items-center md:items-start flex-wrap xl:w-9/12 mx-auto py-44">
            <div class="md:w-6/12 w-full mx-7 sm:mx-7 md:mx-0 lg:mx-0 xl:mx-0">
                <h2 class="text-sm md:text-sm lg:text-lg xl:text-lg text-text-primary font-medium font-sans leading-relaxed">OUR TEAM</h2>
                <h1 class="text-2xl md:text-4xl lg:text-4xl xl:text-4xl text-white font-medium font-sans leading-relaxed mb-5 mt-3">We're a team of designers, engineers and analysts</h1>
                <p class="text-white text-opacity-60 text-lg leading-relaxed">Our team consists of many creative people. We are committed to maintaining quality work as well as speed. These creative people work together to create maximum work results.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="md:w-6/12 w-full mb-10 md:mb-0 mx-7 sm:mx-7 md:mx-0 lg:mx-0 xl:mx-0">
                <img src="img/team.svg" class="w-full" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.overlay__about {
    background-image: url('../img/pattern__works.svg');
    @apply bg-slate-900;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: left;
}

.overlay__team {
    background-image: url('../img/pattern__team.svg');
    @apply bg-slate-900;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use tailwind just in time features.

```
<div class="bg-[url('../img/pattern__works.svg')]">
```

Also you can use this and @apply it in your css code.

```
.overlay__about {
    @apply bg-[url('../img/pattern__works.svg')] bg-slate-900 bg-no-repeat bg-left bg-cover;
}
```

Also if you want to use this in you whole project, you can add it to your tailwind config and add a custom tailwind class for it. You can visit customizing your theme section in [tailwind documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/background-image)

Comment: Does this code removing the border on background images? As you can see in my screenshot there are border on the top of it

Comment: I think adding "bg-cover"  class will remove the sharp border that you talking about. I edit my answer.

Comment: Where i should put your div?

Comment: anyway i just figured out the way. 
i just removing bg cover from the answer
.overlay__team {
        @apply bg-[url('../img/pattern__team.svg')] bg-slate-900 bg-no-repeat bg-right;
    }

Comment: yes. if you don't need backup background color in case background image not loaded, you can remove the background color :)